# Repeating indexes of atoms in PDB file

Tags: pdb

I have a PDB file in which the indexes of atoms are repeated (or better say refreshed) every 99999.

I am using MDtraj software to analyze this pdf file, so these repeating indexes cause some problems.

Does everyone encounter this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistencies like randomly repeated atom indices, maxed out indices at 99999, integer overflowing indices to the negatives (yup, there's a program that has this bug), bad spacing, jumbled order etc. in a PDB are tolerated differently in different programs. Some will carp at missing atoms or non-standard atom names, which are not formatting errors.

In terms of atom indices, these are used in `CONECT` entries, but several programs bond by proximity or by known topology —`CONECT` entries are absent for canonical amino acids. Repeated residue indices and chain letter repeats cause issues with `LINK` and often with peptide chain sequence.

However, in a multimodel PDB the numbers in each model are expected to be reset at every MODEL so if the atom indices reset after the end of a model this is 100% expected.